# org.apache.lucene.Version ClassNotFoundException during elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, jersey-2.0

I am using elasticsearch-rest-high-level client 6.4.0 in my application, I have added all the dependant jars from lucene as listed in maven.

This is the error I am getting

[org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/util/Version] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.util.Version

I was using jersey1 before and my web.xml was like this

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Restful App</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Restful App</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now I have upgraded to jersey2 and changed web.xml to

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Well, you should provide you maven config (`pom.xml`). Problem is probably there.

Comment: Same search method works fine when I run through main, and mine is not a maven project , its a Java Project I downloaded jars manually and added

Comment: I doubt issue is with my web.xml, because rest calls from other applications are not hitting my tomcat now . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002465/web-xml-for-jersey2-not-allowing-rest-calls-from-other-applications