# Web.xml for jersey2 not allowing rest calls from other applications

Tags: java, tomcat8, jersey-2.0

I recently upgraded my jersey jars from version 1 to 2 . With jersey-1 my web.xml mappings were as follows

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Restful App</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Restful App</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have other applications talking to this application through rest calls. After upgrading to jersey 2 I have changed web.xml as follows

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
       </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Normal REST calls within the application seems to work fine,  but rest calls made by other applications are not hitting my application now. No error logs also.

PS: Also I am having elasticsearch configured to talk to this application, even that gives me this error [elasticsearch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002022/org-apache-lucene-version-classnotfoundexception-during-elasticsearch?noredirect=1#comment92908529_53002022)

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? "Not working" doesn't tell us anything. What is happening on the client? What kind of responses are you getting? Status codes? Response body? What happening on the server? What about environment? Dependencies? Do some tracing. Again, I'll reiterate, "not working" is never adequate when trying to get help here. The more information you can provide, the better. Enough for us to _reproduce the problem_ is ideal. A (_MINIMAL_ - not entire project; a stripped down version that reproduces the problem) GitHub repo would also be a plus.

Comment: I am not getting any logs in the tomcat for debugging the issue , rest calls within my application works all fine , the same rest call if its done from another tomcat application its not even hitting the tomcat, again there is no logs in both the applications to debug. I changed the web.xml and specified each of the package names as initparam, its working fine now.